# virtual drive degraded replacement hard drive not found in MegaRAID on Lenovo ThinkServer

Tags: megaraid

Running MegaRAID Storage Manager 16.02.00.04 on a Windows 8.1 Lenovo ThinkServer M 3817 server. Bay 1 had a yellow blinking light so I purchased a replacement and inserted it and after a reboot it's still blinking yellow. Before removing the old HD I made sure to choose the option in the software to "Make Drive Offline" and prepared to remove.

Some errors/warnings in the Event Viewer that may or may not help:

iSCSI discovery via SendTargets failed with error code 0xefff0003 to target portal * 0003260 ROOT\ISCSIPRT\0000_0 .

"The firewall exception to allow Internet Storage Name Server (iSNS) client functionality is not enabled. iSNS client functionality is not available."

Initiator failed to connect to the target. Target IP address and TCP Port number are given in dump data.

Error occurred when processing iSCSI logon request. The request was not retried. Error status is given in the dump data.
The HP CUE DeviceDiscovery Service service hung on starting.
The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) did not load: 
cdrom
dam
VBoxNetAdp

Screenshot of MegaRAID gui:

[image: screenshot of MegaRAID gui]

Pic of yellow blinking light:

[image: pic of yellow blinking light]

logs from reboot:

### MegaRAID Storage Manager 16.02.00.04 Event Log - Generated on Tue Jun 07 16:27:35 EDT 2016

```
ID = 10000
TIME = 07-06-2016 16:02:16
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Successful log on to the server User:  Administrator, Client:,     Access Mode:  Full, Client Time:  2016-06-07,16:02:16

ID = 44
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34151
TIME = 07-06-2016 15:56:31
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Time established since power on:   Time   2016-06-07, 15:56:31      228  Seconds

ID = 195
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34150
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID: 0
"BBU disabled changing WB logical drives to WT, forced WB V(irtual)D(iscs)s are not affected"

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34149
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:4  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  "device inserted type" "disk dev. id: 4"

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34147
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:4

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34146
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:3  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34145
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   3

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34144
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:3

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34143
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:2  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  "dev. ins. type": "dev id: 2"

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34141
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:2

ID = 266
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34140
TIME = 63 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Board Revision:   

ID = 142
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34139
TIME = 63 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Battery Not Present

ID = 1
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34138
TIME = 03 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Image version:   1.40.282-1279

ID = 0
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34137
TIME = 03 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Firmware initialization started:       ( PCI ID   0x60/ 0x1000/ 0x364    / 0x1014)

ID = 195
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34136
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   BBU disabled; changing WB logical drives to WT, Forced WB VDs are not affected

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34135
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:4  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34134
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   4

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34133
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:4

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34132
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:3  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34131
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   3

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34130
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:3

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34129
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:2  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34128
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   2

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34127
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:2

ID = 266
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34126
TIME = 63 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Board Revision:   

ID = 142
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34125
TIME = 63 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Battery Not Present

ID = 1
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34124
TIME = 03 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Image version:   1.40.282-1279

ID = 0
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34123
TIME = 03 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Firmware initialization started:       ( PCI ID   0x60/ 0x1000/ 0x364    / 0x1014)

ID = 42
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34122
TIME = 07-06-2016 15:33:47
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Shutdown command received from host 

ID = 10001
TIME = 07-06-2016 15:29:10
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Successful log out from the server User:  Administrator, Client:  ,     Client Time:  2016-06-07,15:29:10

ID = 44
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34121
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:50:06
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Time established since power on:   Time   2016-06-07, 14:50:06      242  Seconds

ID = 10000
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:50:35
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Successful log on to the server User:  Administrator, Client:  ,     Access Mode:  Full, Client Time:  2016-06-07,14:50:35

ID = 44
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34121
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:50:06
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Time established since power on:   Time   2016-06-07, 14:50:06      242  Seconds

ID = 195
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34120
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   BBU disabled; changing WB logical drives to WT, Forced WB VDs are not affected

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34119
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:4  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34118
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   4

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34117
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:4

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34116
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:3  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34115
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   3

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34114
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:3

ID = 285
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34113
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  PD FRU is:    PD :   -:-:2  FRU : 39M4511

ID = 247
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34112
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Device inserted   Device Type:       Disk  Device Id:   2

ID = 91
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34111
TIME = 82 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   PD inserted:   -:-:2

ID = 266
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34110
TIME = 63 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0  Board Revision:   

ID = 142
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34109
TIME = 63 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Battery Not Present

ID = 1
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34108
TIME = 03 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Image version:   1.40.282-1279

ID = 0
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34107
TIME = 03 seconds from reboot
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Firmware initialization started:       ( PCI ID   0x60/ 0x1000/ 0x364    / 0x1014)

ID = 42
SEQUENCE NUMBER = 34106
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:46:00
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Controller ID:  0   Shutdown command received from host 

ID = 10001
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:43:19
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Successful log out from the server User:  Administrator,   Client Time:  2016-06-07,14:43:19

ID = 10000
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:42:19
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Successful log on to the server User:  Administrator, Client:      Access Mode:  Full, Client Time:  2016-06-07,14:42:19

ID = 10001
TIME = 07-06-2016 14:41:19
LOCALIZED MESSAGE = Successful log out from the server User:  Administrator,
```

Client:       Client Time:  2016-06-07,14:41:19

Comment: Windows 8.1 on a server chassis ?

Comment: Yep my predecessor left this for me haven't figured out why.